# minio Unsupported OkHttp library found. Must use okhttp >= 4.8.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, minio

after using minio as instructions and fixing it with ways below, I failed.what can i do to solve this bug

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.minio</groupId>
        <artifactId>minio</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also experienced this issues with `io.minio:minio:8.3.6`, but was able to force a newer version of `okhttp`, which works with the MinIO client library. Here is the snippet of `build.gradle` (should work similar with Maven):

```
implementation("io.minio:minio:8.3.6")    
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3")
```

In my case it was probably caused by `spring-boot-dependencies` coming with the spring dependency plugin, which manages a lot of dependencies containing also `okhttp` and thus forces the downgrade.

See also:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.3
- https://github.com/minio/minio-java/issues/1298

## Update

With Spring Boot 2.7.0, the fix is no longer required, since the version requirements for okhttp have been updated. The MinIO dependency should work now out of the box.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've solved this issue!

Comment: Hi, will it have problems since this method violates the spring boot dependencies?

Comment: I just tried it with Spring Boot `2.6.6` combined with MinIO `8.3.8` and it still works without problems using the described method.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with above specified to connect minio azure s3 bucker using springboot 2.7.8 combined with Minio 8.3.6. i'm getting null object. below is my code can any one suggest what wrong i'm doing here. `            MinioClient client = MinioClient.builder()
                    .endpoint(HttpUrl.parse(minioUrl))
                    //.httpClient(httpClient)
                    .credentials(accessKey, accessSecret)
                    .build(); `